# Invalid number of rows in section while trying to reload using reloadsections

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two sections in the tableview.

1. Rows in section 0 would change when receiving remote notification (insert) or an expired timer (delete).
2. Section 1 would always have 8 rows and would change when user refresh, all the 8 items would be changed.

I am trying to reload the entire section 0 after the dateset has changed (use refreshed) using.

```
self.candidates.remoteAll()
for object in json {
    let candidate = Candidate(/* Some data */)
    self.candidates.append(candidate!)
}

self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .automatic)
```

and it somehow throws

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyExceptionInvalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

The number of inconsistent rows are not fixed, sometimes there are 2 before the update and 1 after, sometimes is 0 before and 1 after the update. My guess is that section 0 was inserting or delete rows while user trying to refresh section 1.

But I was trying to refresh section 1, section 0 should do no effect whether or not it has a consistent number of rows. Where am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**Update**

Here is `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        if let invitations = self.invitations {
            return invitations.count
        }
        return 0
    case 1:
        return self.candidates.count
    default: return 0
    }
}
```

I am using Realm Result on section 0, and Array on section 1.

Comment: Can you post your numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Your reload call is reloading section 1, not section 0, but it seems that you are adding an object to the array but not calling `insertRows` to tell the tableview about the new row

Comment: @ViniApp I updated my post, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry I forgot to mention, I did call `self.candidates.remoteAll()` before appending new objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this line of code should be: `self.candidates.removeAll()`